# Generating a random with a specific limited size

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could someone explain to me how I can use random to generate a list consisting of numbers that differ from 0 to 9 and the size should be fixed between 49 and 98?

```
random_number = [random.randint(0,9) for _ in range()]
```

I think I should use this line, but I am not sure how to limit the random_number which gets generated to be a number consisting of 49 to 98 numbers.

Could someone help me clarifying this?

Comment: Is the fixed size between 49 and 98 known or is that random too?

Comment: `random_number = [random.randint(49,98) for _ in range()]`?

Comment: Random too. So it should give a random size between 49 and 98.

Comment: `random_number = [random.randint(0,9) for _ in range(random.randint(49, 98))]` if the size is also random

Comment: It is clear to me now. Thanks a lot all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) to generate a list of random entries from a range, pass `k=` to determine the size. We can pass `k=random.randint(49, 98)` to generate a list with a random length in that range

```
import random
random.choices(range(0, 9), k=random.randint(49, 98))
```

Comment: I understand, but the challenge I am facing is more about how to get a random number for the size. This random number of the size should be between the values 49 and 98.                               I can not find out how to set these specific size limits and that it should get a random number in between them.

Comment: Thanks, this did work out for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

`[random.randint(0,9) for _ in range(random.randint(49,98))]`

This should do what you want, no? Range accepts a number, so if we randomly generate a number between 49 and 98 and pass it to range, we'll get a list of 49 to 98 items, which will be iterated over.

Edit: Seems a comment beat me to it. Tragic.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It works out for me now